# What was bernanosian about Camus's call to sacrifice in the resistance newspaper Combat?

Tags: french-language, albert-camus, georges-bernanos

For several years, Albert Camus was editor-in-chief of [*Combat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_(newspaper)), a clandestine newspaper of the French Resistance. In his biography *Albert Camus, fils d'Alger* ("Albert Camus, son of Algiers", Fayard 2010, Pluriel 2013) Alain Vircondelet (on page 290) writes about Camus's contribution to issue 58 of the newspaper:

> il dénonce Pétain et ses acolytes, et en appelle au sacrifice des Français avec des accents bernanosiens.

English translation:

> he denounces Pétain and his sidekicks, and calls on the French onto sacrifice with a Bernanosian ring.

Does this refer to something in Bernanos's fiction, his non-fiction or his biography?